# Search cells in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have an Excel workbook with multiple worksheets. I'm using Excel 2013. First worksheet contains the list of items.

The other worksheets contains the same items but in scattered fashion (with lot of cell formatting) and not in any particular order.

I have tried my hand on the following Excel functions

```
SEARCH  
FIND
VLOOKUP
HLOOKUP
LOOKUP
INDEX
MATCH
```

Edit: Please find the image below to illustrate my requirement.
The Apple in Worksheet1 is available in Worksheet2 - so I need Excel to put a "YES" next to it in worksheet1.
[image]

Comment: Could you add some sample data please.

Comment: This question is not clear, sorry, and will likely be closed... You need to give more examples or reword, as it is, we can't help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest a `Countif()` inside an if statement. Say you knew the name (Apple, Banana, Orange, etc) would be in column A, B or C on sheet2, and your list of items on sheet1 start in cell A1, the type the below formula in B1 and drag down:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:C,A1)>0,"Yes","No")
```

Note: I don't have Excel 2013 so I can't test this exactly `Sheet2!` might need to be `Worksheet2!`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea Kyle, probably the question was not clear as much as it should be - appreciate your efforts!